# Horizontal merging of multiple text files with uneven rows

Tags: merge, find, paste

Apologies beforehand if the problem below may seem as duplicate but I haven't found any suitable solutions.

I am trying to merge several text files horizontally. Below is a format description :

1) All files contain "_final_significant" as a common part in their filename (e.g File1_final_significant.txt, File2_final_significant.txt etc)

2) These files are located in different subdirectories. Each folder contains one *_final_significant.txt file along with other .txt files

e.g

```
Folder 1
File1_final_significant.txt
Irrelevantfile.txt

Folder 2
File2_final_significant.txt
Irrelevantfile.txt
etc
```

I want to merge only the _final_significant.txt files from all folders.

3) Each of the target file has uneven number of rows and data in three columns, separated by space. No value is shared between target files.

e.g

```
File1_final_significant.txt
Name1 Name2 Value1
Name3 Name4 Value2
n rows

File2_final_significant.txt
Name5 Name6 Value3
Name7 Name8 Value4
k rows
```

The desired output is

```
Merged_file.txt

Name1 Name2 Value1 Name5 Name6 Value3 etc
Name3 Name4 Value2 Name7 Name8 Value4 etc
n rows             k rows
```

I know that this is a common question and so far I tried several suggestions I found from similar posts with no success. I came across the following solution but instead of merging horizontally my files contents it merges the file directories.

```
find /path_to_files -type f -name '*final_significant*' | xargs | paste -s >> merged_file.txt
```

This is the first time I am using find or paste commands so I would appreciate your help and time. Please include only bash options in the answer, the above is part of a much larger and complicated script and I would prefer not to shift to perl/R etc.

Many thanks for your time

Comment: Shouldn't you take the pipe out of `xargs | paste -s `?

Comment: What I get is the following : `/path_to_files/Folder1/File1_final_significant.txt /path_to_files/Folder2/File2_final_significant.txt etc` so I am getting the directories paths merged not the file contents.

Answer (score 0):

OK got the answer myself, completely wrong approach the one in the original post (I am obviously a newbie) :

```
find /path_to_files -type f -name '*final_significant*' -exec paste {} +  >> merged_file.txt
```

However now I am facing the usual problem of pasting files with uneven number of rows-that is columns that are messed up. Can anyone please modify the code above so as to get the desired output as indicated above? Already tried several awk and sed solutions to no use in my case.
Thank you!